# Rounding multiple values in a way that i always get the same sum

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I'm designing a dynamic column layout, my problem occurs when the rounding of my `col` will be >12 (I also don't want it to be <12)

```
foreach(var shelf in Shelves)
{
    double col = (12.0 * shelf.Width) / SumShelvesWidth;
    ShelvesCol.Add((Int32)Math.Round(col));
}
```

**Example**

```
SumShelvesWidth=69;
Shelves.Width = [21,27,21];

col[0] = (12*21)/69 =>~3,65;
col[1] = (12*27)/69 =>~4,69;
col[2] = (12*21)/69 =>~3,65;

ShelvesCol[0] = 4;
ShelvesCol[1] = 5;
ShelvesCol[2] = 4;
//SUM OF COL > 12;
```

How can I successfully round so I will have a sum of 12 every time?

Comment: The way I see this, your problem lies not with rounding, but with your very concept. You need a sum of exactly 12. Yet you also want integers only, which is why you waste .35 on 0 and 2 and .31 on 1. With these values, you would have to round down to at least the nearest .5. But this would be narrower than the shelf actually is.
Result: Three such shelves won't fit if rounding is required. Re-think what exactly you want and whether it matches reality.

Comment: You cannot do this with rounding numbers.

In my opinion, you need to round all the columns **except** the last one, and then make the last one to fit the condition of 12. In more complex scenarios this does not need to be the last one but one selected in some way, but this is in the implementation.